# Runtime automation unspecified error in excel VBA 2013

Tags: excel, vba, dom

I am trying running a piece of VBA code in excel 2013 to access some data from our intranet site and I am getting a  run time error 2147467259 (80004005) - Automation error unspecified error.

```
Sub AccessWar()

    Dim oIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim oHTML As HTMLDocument
    Set oIE = New InternetExplorer
    oIE.Navigate ("http://iscls3apps/WAR40/aspx/WAR40AllReports.aspx")
    oHTML = oIE.document

End Sub
```

I am new to excel VBA and do not have much idea. Any pointers would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use IE with VBA too but it seemed that the running don't really care if the loading of the page in IE is done or not!

So I made i little routine that navigate and wait, just by adding

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

after every navigate... No super efficient but VBA is not made to parse information on the web, you could use so more approriate languages if you are willing to! ;)